# java.lang.ClassCastException error in restfull webservice

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, rest

I am developing a website using `restfull webservice`. I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ehr.data.CombineClass cannot be cast to java.util.Collection.
```

Full Exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ehr.data.CombineClass cannot be cast to java.util.Collection] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ehr.data.CombineClass cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CollectionContainerPolicy.addInto(CollectionContainerPolicy.java:68)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ContainerPolicy.addInto(ContainerPolicy.java:128)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:631)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1075)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Patient Class:

```
package com.ehr.data;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient")
public class Patient {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int patientId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String cnic;
private String contactNumber;
private String homeNumber;
private String country;
private String city;
private String town;
private String streetNo;
private String houseNo;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;
public int getPatientId() {
    return patientId;
}
public void setPatientId(int patientId) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getCnic() {
    return cnic;
}
public void setCnic(String cnic) {
    this.cnic = cnic;
}
public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
public String getHomeNumber() {
    return homeNumber;
}
public void setHomeNumber(String homeNumber) {
    this.homeNumber = homeNumber;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getTown() {
    return town;
}
public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}
public String getStreetNo() {
    return streetNo;
}
public void setStreetNo(String streetNo) {
    this.streetNo = streetNo;
}
public String getHouseNo() {
    return houseNo;
}
public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
    this.houseNo = houseNo;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Appointment Class:

```
package com.ehr.data;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Appointment")
public class Appointment {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
private int appointmentId;
private int day;
@OneToOne
private Patient patient;
public int getAppointmentId() {
    return appointmentId;
}
public void setAppointmentId(int appointmentId) {
    this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
}
public Patient getPatient() {
    return patient;
}
public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
    this.patient = patient;
}
public int getDay() {
    return day;
}
public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}
}
```

CombineClass Class: this class has object of Appointment class and Patient class

```
package com.ehr.data;
public class CombineClass {
private Appointment appointment;
private Patient patient;
public Appointment getAppointment() {
    return appointment;
}
public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
    this.appointment = appointment;
}
public Patient getPatient() {
    return patient;
}
public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
    this.patient = patient;
}
}
```

AppointmentService Class:

```
package com.ehr.dao;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.ehr.data.Appointment;
import com.ehr.data.CombineClass;
import com.ehr.data.Patient;
public class AppointmentService {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

public CombineClass createNewAppointment(CombineClass appointment){

    try{
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient = (Patient)(appointment).getPatient();
        Appointment appointment1 = new Appointment();
        appointment1 = (Appointment)(appointment).getAppointment();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(appointment1);
        session.save(patient);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return appointment;
}
}
```

AppointmentResource Class:

```
package org.Webapp.resource;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.ehr.dao.AppointmentService;
import com.ehr.data.CombineClass;
@Path("appointments")
public class AppointmentResource {

AppointmentService appointmentService = new AppointmentService();

@Path("new")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CombineClass createNewAppointment(CombineClass appointment){
    return appointmentService.createNewAppointment(appointment);
}
}
```

Input Passing to web service:

```
[
{
    "day":10
},
{
"firstName":"Asad",
"lastName":"Saleem",
"age":23,
"cnic":"1234567890",
"contactNumber":"1234566",
"homeNumber":"1321546",
"country":"pak",
"city":"rwp",
"town":"abc",
"streetNo":"a1",
"houseNo":"xyz",
"email":"abc@gmail.com",
"username":"asad",
"password":"123"
}
]
```

kindly identify where is the error i shall be very thankful to

Comment: You should be getting a full stack trace with your `java.lang.ClassCastException`.  It would tell you the exact class, method, and line number.  If you post the full stack trace I'm sure someone can explain it to you.

Comment: @BenM. ok i will post the stack trace

Comment: @BenM. check it i provide full excepton can u identify error.

Comment: Also post the input that you are passing to the REST service

Comment: @PradeepPati i include the input that i m passing to web service kindly identify my mistake.

Comment: @PradeepPati i include the input kindly identify the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [] brackets from your input json.

Jersey is trying to map your `CombineClass` to `Collection` because you are passing BRACKETS in the json input and eventually failing because it can't cast .

```
 public CombineClass createNewAppointment(CombineClass appointment){
 [//REMOVE THIS
 {
   "day":10
 },
 {
 "firstName":"Asad",
 "lastName":"Saleem",
 "age":23,
 "cnic":"1234567890",
 "contactNumber":"1234566",
 "homeNumber":"1321546",
 "country":"pak",
"city":"rwp",
"town":"abc",
"streetNo":"a1",
"houseNo":"xyz",
"email":"abc@gmail.com",
"username":"asad",
"password":"123"
}
]///REMOVE THIS
```

Comment: Peter Friberg : May i know why the answer is downvoted.